# How to use git for file synchronization?

Tags: git, synchronization

I have a need for distributed file synchronization.  So first of all, any suggestions?  My idea is git since speed is an issue.

My git knowledge is pretty rudimentary though so here's what I did.

I downloaded the portable git (I'm on PC so msysgit).
I placed a copy into c:\root\git and a copy into c:\root\git c:\client\git\

I created a directory c:\temp\root\content and created some files in it

```
c:\root\content>..\git\bin\git.exe init
c:\root\content>..\git\bin\git.exe add *
c:\root\content>..\git\bin\git.exe commit -f
c:\client>..\git\bin\git.exe clone file:///c:\root\content
```

This creates a content directory but it is empty!  The files committed to root are not there.

Also when I do a pull command I get

```
C:\temp\client\content\content>c:\temp\client\git\bin\git.exe pull
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Your configuration specifies to merge the ref 'master' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched
```

Clearly I'm missing a concept.  What's going on?

Comment: If you just want synchronisation, I would say rsync is a better choice of tool.

Comment: rsync is good for one-way synchronization, if you want to sync files that might change in two places, I suggest looking at unison

Comment: rsync is unix only right?  Can't afford to presume anything about the platform.

Comment: @George: I use rsync on OS X and Windows all the time. So, no, it's not Unix only.

Comment: @George: I would argue that rsync is better supported on Windows (cwRsync) than Git is. But better yet, +1 on davr's suggestion of Unison (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Comment: interesting.  Ok rsync it is.

Comment: Since you're using Windows, Microsoft's SyncToy may be easier to use than rsync (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)

Comment: @DataWraith - SyncToy does not help with distributed synchronization and like I said, I can't afford to presume the platform is Windows

Comment: Both rsync and unison have ports to linux/mac/windows

Comment: You should look up git-annex which is created exactly for this reason.

Answer (score 5):

Check into http://sparkleshare.org/

Sparkleshare gives you a user experience similar to Dropbox, except that it's underlying sync engine is git. It's not the most stable thing, but you can watch it's log output to see what git commands it's going to achieve seamless syncing. Once you learn those, you can simply make your own sync scripts that are stable. I think most of sparkleshare's problems are in the GUI.

Answer (score 5):

[git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) could be another tool to consider.

Comment: Yes, git-annex is made for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Git *can* be a good tool for synchronizing source between development and production, for one reason: It makes it easy to "hot fix" in production and check the fix back into the tree.  Of course you should always reproduce the bug in a development or test environment and fix it there, but sometimes you can't.

Instead of `git add *`, use `git add .`

Use `git status` before committing to make sure that the appropriate files are staged for commit.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce your steps.

`git commit -f` didn't do anything with the 1.6.5.1 version I just installed. But it should give you a long error message.

```
mkdir repo1 repo2
cd repo1
git init
( create files )
git add *
git commit -m "initial commit"
cd ..\repo2
git clone ..\repo1 .
```

and the files I created in `repo1` appear in `repo2`.

Answer (score 1):

As davr suggested in the comments, you might try [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). By [having all your hosts sync with a central hub](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/beta/unison-manual.html#usingmultiple), you can have n-way synchronization. Unison doesn't preserve history, so if you want that you should schedule [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) to run every day on one of your hosts (preferably whichever one has the largest, most reliable hard drive). Both tools have Windows binaries.

I've also considered using Git for file synchronization, but manually adding, committing, pulling and merging is too much work (a tool is only useful if you use it). In my head I've designed a little Python or Ruby system tray process to watch your repo for changes, nag you when it's dirty, have options for autocommit after a period of no changes, and also do auto push/pull. Resolving merge conflicts would be done using an existing tool.

For more details check out [this article](http://wiki.pdxhub.org/backup/) I just wrote about personal file synchronization.